# Uniqueness of a partial differential equation with expected values

Tags: partial-differential-equations, random-variables, expected-value

Let $ X $ be a random variable distributed according to the cumulative distribution function $P$ and density function $p$ with full support on $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}_+$.

I am trying to find a function $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ (or a class of functions), where $[c,d]\subset \mathbb{R}_+$, that solves the following differential equation:

$$ \int_a^b g(x,y) f_y(x,y) p(x) dx = \int_a^b f(x,y) p(x) dx, \qquad \qquad (1) $$

where $g:[a,b]\times[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a known function that is continuously differentiable and increasing in $x$ and decreasing in $y$, and $f_y(x,y) := \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) $ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$.

A pointwise solution exists – that is, a solution to $$g(x,y)f_y(x,y)=f(x,y)$$ is $$f(x,y)=a(x)\exp\left(\int_1^y\frac{1}{g(x,s)}dx\right)$$ for any $a(x) \in \mathbb{R}$. This solution also solves the partial differential equation with expected values.

My question hence is, When is the pointwise solution unique to (1) and is there more general solutions to the original partial differential equation given in (1)?